# Yocto/Bitbake How to specify case sensitive variable replacement

Tags: python, yocto, bitbake

I have a problem in yocto where I declare a variable in my 
`build/bblayers.conf`

```
VAR="strINg"
```

then when I use it in `meta-example/recipes-kernel/linux/linuxexamplekernel.bb`
in the Source Uri variable

```
SRC_URI="http://${VAR}.example.com/"
```

the value of `${VAR}` gets case corrected from 'strINg' to `string` when I need the case to stay the same. The capitals in the middle of the string have to stay the same.

Does anyone know how to make bitbake replace the variable as is with no case correction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no "case correction". You are seeing some other failure -- `bitbake -e <recipe> | grep SRC_URI` and the same for VAR might be useful. Also:

```
${VAR}="strINg"
```

this should be

```
VAR = "strINg"
```

I assume you know that bblayers.conf is a fairly surprising place to define a variable like this...

Comment: Thank you, I edited the variable syntax. hmm I'll take a look at through `bitbake -e | grep SRC_URI` and see what i can find. You're right I shouldn't declare the variable in bblayers.conf

Comment: If the resource in the SRC_URI actually changes, have you noticed you would need to change the checksums as well? Not changing the checksums leads to a situation where bitbake decides it doesn't need to download from the new URI (because it already has a file with the correct checksum). I wonder if you are trying to solve the wrong problem: are you sure you really want to change the SRC_URI? It's quite unusual.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Turns out the case correction was being done by `wget` in the back end during the `do_fetch` phase. Absolutely right about the checksums if the tagged commit/release changes the checksums would also need to change. My particular problem meant that I needed to use URI's in all lower case but I will mark the answer as correct because  bitbake does not do any "case correction"